# xfce Desktop Doesn't Load In

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce

I'm running into this strange issue when using xfce where my desktop (wallpaper + desktop icons) won't load in after a reboot until I log out and back in. I don't believe I messed with any settings that would affect this, but I'm not entirely sure. Do you guys have any solutions other than reinstalling xfce and if not, is there some way to back up my themes + settings so that I can restore them after a reinstall?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce as a desktop environment

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Are you running Ubuntu or Xubuntu?  and what DEsktops have you got installed?    (*I ask this as I had issues at one time where multiple DEsktops caused this issue*).  I believe your configs are stored in ~/.config/xfce4/ , but additional themes you've added, or other details can be elsewhere too.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce as a desktop environment (only have unity and xfce currently installed). The issue is really just an annoying bug, and so I don't know if its worth the hassle to go through and try reinstalling xfce

Comment: @HF1, better to add such important info into question by editing & updating it.

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall Xubuntu meta package? You can try this way with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

this issue seems to be common with the 16.04 version after the latest update.

**The solution as of now is to wait until Ubuntu has a fix for it.**

[Check here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060710/messed-menus-labels-buttons-colors-after-latest-update-on-july-2018/1060716#1060716)

It is the same problem and I suggested him to do an upgrade, I would suggest you to do so only if all the packages support the latest version.

Try contacting Ubuntu for the issue. Else, I would suggest to do an upgrade *(not recommended if packages unsupported may break your applications)* as it's a faster solution because usually the fix takes time.

**P.S: In case it annoys you while working, I am attaching the solution if you need to do an upgrade.**

Try using the terminal and do `sudo update-manager` / go to Software & Updates and enable notify for any new version!

And do this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

To directly do the upgrade then:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core  
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

In case you were wondering if you could downgrade the update, then check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) as he explains why downgrade is not recommended.

Also, there's also a way that you could clean install the older version of Ubuntu(although, why would you do that as some of your app data might be lost).

Comment: Might try installing 18.04 since it has some features that would be of use to me and might solve this issue. 


Also, it appears as though `sudo do-release-update` currently doesn't work (states that no new release was found). Seems as though it'll still be a few days until Ubuntu allows us to use this method to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Refer to this link upgrading from Ubuntu section. You can upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @HF1 Is it Solved?